# How to loop through Google Maps API's Travel mode

Tags: javascript, google-maps, object, google-maps-api-3

I am attempting to use JavaScript to get a set of directions for driving, walking and bicycling from the Google Maps JavaScript API by looping through the google.maps.TravelMode properties. I am trying to do this by using a square bracket and the method name, however I get the following error message when I do it:

> Uncaught InvalidValueError: in property travelMode: undefined

Here is the loop:

```
var methods = new Array("DRIVING", "WALKING", "BICYCLING");
            $.each(methods, function(method) {
                request.travelMode = google.maps.TravelMode[method];
                directionsService.route(request, function(response) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    console.log(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
                });
            });
```

I believe it to be an error with the third line in the code section above.

If I print out the google.maps.TravelMode object to the console, it comes up with the following:

```
Object {
    DRIVING: "DRIVING",
    WALKING: "WALKING",
    BICYCLING: "BICYCLING",
    TRANSIT: "TRANSIT"
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The directions service is asynchronous.  It will only support one request at a time.  Either create an instance for each request (and hope you don't run into the query limit) or send the next request when you get the result from the previous request.  Note that the directions renderer is going to have a similar issue (it will only display one route at a time). If that doesn't help, perhaps you can create a jsfiddle that exhibits the issue.

Comment: You're right @geocodezip, one I had implemented the fix (answer below) the results are just those of bicycling. how would I do that? I have a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/FLT2n/ for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the callback of `$.each` has two arguments, key and value, you must use the 2nd argument(currently you try to access `google.maps.TravelMode.0` , `google.maps.TravelMode.1`  , `google.maps.TravelMode.2`):

```
$.each(methods, function(key, method){/**/}
```