# Multiple Google Maps directions requests returning last response for all requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use the Google Maps Directions service to return three methods of travel for the same route (driving, walking and bicycling). I can successfully loop through the array of methods and put them in the relevant request, but all three requests return the response for bicycling, the last method in the array. Is this to do with the requests sent to Google being asynchronous?

The offending code seems to be in the for each loop in this code:

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5072, 0.1275);
var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(53.7997, 1.5492);
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'));
var request = {
    origin: origin,
    destination: destination
};
var methods = new Array("DRIVING", "WALKING", "BICYCLING");
var route = new Array();
$.each(methods, function(key, method) {
    request.travelMode = google.maps.TravelMode[method];
    console.log(request.travelMode);
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsService.route(request, function(response) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        route[method] = directionsDisplay.getDirections();
        console.log(route[method].routes[0].legs[0].steps[0].travel_mode);
        //console.log(route.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text);
        //console.log(Math.round(Math.round(route.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value/1000)*0.6214));
    });
});
```

Please look at the code in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLT2n/1/) to find the full code. The methods which shoould be sent are printed out in the console, followed by the method of travel contained in the response.

Comment: The directions service is asynchronous.  See my comment in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232804/how-to-loop-through-google-maps-apis-travel-mode)

Comment: Hi @geocodezip, I replied to you with the information you requested :) I'm still unsure as to how to implement what you suggested though :/

Comment: updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLT2n/3/) (uses function closure.

Answer (score 1):

`request` is a reference, all changes on this reference will be visible everywhere where you use this reference.

Create a copy of request (with the desired travelMode) and use this copy as argument for `route()`

```
directionsService.route($.extend({},
                                 request,
                                 {travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[method]}), 
                        function(response) {/*your code */});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FLT2n/5/